# How to find element by Full xPath in Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, phantomjs

I want to find element by xPath that i just copied from browser HTML viewer. Is there any good way to use it? How can i locate this element?

For example this:

1)**HTML**

```
<span class="fifth-star star-common" data-star-index="5" jsaction="click:JdtzLb;mouseenter:UYGLjf"> </span>
```

**xPath**

```
/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[5]
```

2)
**HTML**

```
<a class="actionlink" href="javascript:CCommentThread.DeleteComment( 'PublishedFile_Public_76561198045856086_852822766_0', '133257324794187128' );">Удалить</a>
```

**xPath**

```
//*[@id="comment"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]
```

*I tried this way*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/span[5]"));
```

And this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"comment\"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]"));
```

Comment: For the good way, you need to share HTML as well...:)

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur Done

Comment: Is both elements HTML are unique?? If not Only element's HTML is not enough to locate it uniquely, need to share block of the HTML. thanks..:)

Answer (score 1):

Use `single quotes` in the XPATH instead of escaping using `\`

try this way:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='comment']/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]"));
```

please share block code, in case of more efficient `XPATH`.

---

Other ways:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'javascript:CCommentThread.DeleteComment')]"));
```

Comment: ```ReferenceError: By is not defined```

Comment: import By class as follows in your code `org.openqa.selenium.By`